# Ext JS application shows blank page

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am a newbie in Ext JS. I am creating the very first application explained in this tutorial: http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-ext-js-4 and as mentioned in it I have created index.html with the following contents:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hello Ext</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

and app.js with following code:

```
<a href="#!/api/Ext-method-application" rel="Ext-method-application"     class="docClass">Ext.application</a>({
name: 'HelloExt',
launch: function() {
    <a href="#!/api/Ext-method-create" rel="Ext-method-create"  class="docClass">Ext.create</a>('<a href="#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport"  rel="Ext.container.Viewport" class="docClass">Ext.container.Viewport</a>', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Hello Ext',
                html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
            }
        ]
    });
}
});
```

But it shows me blank page. If I debug it using Chrome developer tools, it shows me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in app.js:1

I have tried hard but got no idea what is going wrong in app.js

I am sure my framework is properly set up and working, but the page is blank when it is loaded.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the path to your ext-debug.js (extjs/ext-debug.js) is correct? Looks to me like it was never loaded.

Comment: @Parzifal.. yes, I am 100% sure about it... There is something wrong in app.js file, which I am not able to figure out :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably have better luck using real Javascript instead of their wrongly copy/pasted html wrapped javascript text:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Hello Ext',
                    html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this a common issue online and it's referred to the use of Ext3 instead of Ext4, the code runs without any problems if you're using the right version of Ext wich is in this case Ext4.